# How to I define activities in presence.activities?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make the bot add a streaming role to someone when they go live. Everyone tells me my code is right but when I start the bot I get "cannot read property 'activities' of undefined". oldMember and newMember used to be oldPresence and newPresence which didn't work either.

```
client.on('presenceUpdate', (oldMember, newMember) => {
    const guild = client.guilds.cache.get('614134721533968484');
    const streamingRole = guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.id === '720050658149138444');
    const oldGame = oldMember.activities.find(activity => activity.type === 'STREAMING') ? true : false;
    const newGame = newMember.activities.find(activity => activity.type === 'STREAMING') ? true : false;
      
    //if (newMember.user.bot || oldMember.presence.activities !== newMember.presence.activities) return;
    
    if (!oldGame && newGame) {         // Started playing.
      newMember.roles.add(streamingRole)
        .then(() => console.log(`${streamingRole.name} added to ${newMember.user.tag}.`))
        .catch(console.error);
    } else if (oldGame && !newGame) {  // Stopped playing.
      newMember.roles.remove(streamingRole)
        .then(() => console.log(`${streamingRole.name} removed from ${newMember.user.tag}.`))
        .catch(console.error);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the `presence` property to access the GuildMember's activities

```js
const oldGame = oldMember.presence.activities.find(activity => activity.type === 'STREAMING') ? true : false;
const newGame = newMember.presence.activities.find(activity => activity.type === 'STREAMING') ? true : false;
```

Comment: I had tried that already as well and I had the same issue. I found people saying you didn’t need it so I took it away.